# Dont know how to form a query in a propper way

Tags: mysql

I want to set a query which asks "show me all people from table users which are not found in table employees". Im looking for unemployed people

```
SELECT user.name,user.surname,user.user_id,employee.employee_id,employee.user_id
FROM user
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.user_id=user.user_id
WHERE user.user_id <> employee.user_id
```

Tables are linked via `user.user_id` --> `employee.user_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this sort of query using an `outer join`, and checking for a null value in the outer table.

Here is a slight modification of your query, changing it to an outer join, and looking for a null value being returned.

**Edit**: I've also added in a third table, containing the `manager` table, as per the comment to this answer.

```
SELECT 
    user.name,user.surname,user.user_id,employee.employee_id,employee.user_id 
FROM 
    user 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employee 
        ON employee.user_id=user.user_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN manager
        ON manager.user_id=user.user_id 
WHERE 
    -- The columns from employee and manager get returned with null values if there is no match
    employee.user_id is null 
    and manager.user_id is null
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks @RToyo. 
One more question. A couple of those users that are unemployed are managers and theyr manager role is shown in a diferent table but they are enlisted in users. How to stop this query from showing them?

Comment: @brika28: Sounds like you might need to add another `LEFT JOIN` and null check. However, that will likely need to be a new question.

Comment: @Zack:Thanks I will try on my own from here. No pain no gain!

Comment: @brika28 Glad it worked! As Zach mentioned, if the manager lookup is in a different table, you'll need to add that table to the query as a left outer join, and check it for nulls as well. I've updated the answer to include a `manager` table.

Comment: @RToyo : thanks guys I managed to do it with another     <left join>